# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass Error help!

Tags: 7, database

When trying to access my image file from my database i get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\drupal-7.25\sites\all\modules\database\database_ex.module on line 99

note: line 99 is **$uri = $value['url'];**

```
function database_ex_form_submission($uri) {
  $result = db_query("SELECT myimage FROM example");
  $records = $result->fetchAll();

  $res = $result->execute();

  foreach ($records as $value) {
    $uri = $value['url'];
    $url = file_create_url($uri);
  }
}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: As Nicolas PERNOT said , you cannot use object as array. Use $value['url'] as $value->url.
Otherwise first print the $value in foreach as check whether it is object or an array.

Answer (score 1):

You say :

> note: line 99 is $uri = $value['url'];

So:

`$value` isn't an array and you can't write `$value['url'];`.

In fact `$value` is an object and you have to use this syntax `$value->url;`